# How do I store key.pem (I presume?) in the app so I can use it with me MySSLSocketFactory class?

Tags: android, openssl, keystore

Im tyring to wrap my head around this problem. I have created a `cert.pem` and a `key.pem` on my server by running `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`. I believe this is know as self signing, correct?

I want to enable SSL comunication with the app. How do I store `key.pem` (I presume? Is that the right one?) in the app so I can use it with my `MySSLSocketFactory` class? And set the SSL factory of the httpclient.

Or am I completely missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

no you can't do it , this is clear text issue you should use network Security Config instead

Comment: you can find it in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: I already have ```android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"``` in manifest. And I have already tried ```https://```